# On runnig golang server on public ip gives error

Tags: go, server, apache2

i am trying to run a golang server on a public ip which i bought. I have server written in go. But it error on this line

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS("mywebsitename.io:3000","keys/cert.pem","keys/privkey.pem", nil))
```

error:

> listen tcp 3.263.418.111:3000: bind: cannot assign requested address
>   exit status 1

but it runs on private ip on port 3000.

Comment: Does that server have a network interface with that address?

Comment: 3.263.418.111 Is not a valid IP address.

Answer (score 2):

First, server where your service will run must have your public IP assigned to network interface.

If your service runs in container and is reachable through e.g. reverse proxy you will need to listen on a private container address and port that is then mapped to your public IP (or all container addresses by just specifying port like `ListenAndServeTLS(":port")`).

NOTE: `3.263.418.111` is not a valid IP address even for example purposes (range of each octet is `0-255`); I assume just came up with numbers to hide your real public address.